# How I search a string in core data with swift 3?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I want to search a string in my DB and it keeps returning all records from core data. The other questions I saw here didn't work. Suggestions?

```
var users:[Users] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let myrequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '%@'", "alex")
        myrequest.predicate = predicate

        do{
            users = try context.fetch(myrequest) as! [Users]

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you get if you set it this way: **let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = 'alex'")** ?

Comment: all the records :/

Comment: OK - then you have something else quirky going on. Double-check your field names, record sets, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's working now. this is the final code. Maybe it will help someone in the future :) thanks for the help guys.

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let query:NSFetchRequest<Users> = Users.fetchRequest()
        let key = "alex"

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", key)
        query.predicate = predicate

        do{
            users = try context.fetch(query)
            print(users.count)

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use single quotes in your predicate. Try with this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "alex")
myrequest.predicate = predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this in **do** case

```
users = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
```

Comment: keep fetching all records